# R Showing Different Results in forward and backward for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I get different answers while searching for a certain element in an array if I am searching forward or backwards using a for loop.

Example: Code that gives CORRECT ANSWER

```
vg   = rep(seq(0.9,1.1,0.01),90)
vals = seq(0.9,1.05,0.01)

for(val in vals){
  idx = c()
  idx = which((vg) %in% (val))
  cat(val,":",length(idx),"\t")
}
```

This Code gives: 
0.9 : 90        0.91 : 90       0.92 : 90       0.93 : 90       0.94 : 90       0.95 : 90       0.96 : 90       0.97 : 90    0.98 : 90       0.99 : 90       1 : 90  1.01 : 90       1.02 : 90       1.03 : 90       1.04 : 90       1.05 : 90

WHICH IS CORRECT.  But if I change the seq of the vg variable above using the CODE below:

```
vg   = rep(seq(1.1,0.9,-0.01),90)
vals = seq(0.9,1.05,0.01)

for(val in vals){
  idx = c()
  idx = which((vg) %in% (val))
  cat(val,":",length(idx),"\t")
}
```

I get the answer shown below, WHICH SHOWS 0 NUMBER OF ELEMENTS WHILE SEARCHING FOR 0.96, 0.97 etc.

**0.9 : 0**         **0.91 : 0        0.92 : 0**        0.93 : 90       0.94 : 90       0.95 : 90       **0.96 : 0        0.97 : 0     0.98 : 0        0.99 : 0**        1 : 90  1.01 : 90       1.02 : 90       1.03 : 90       1.04 : 90       1.05 : 90

Why is this discrepancy since we are searching for the exactly same elements in both the codes? Is this a R Bug?

Comment: This is most likely a floating point problem, and almost certainly not an R bug. See the FAQ 7.31 : http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: This is not a floating point problem since we are generating all the  values in the program itself. When I compare using which(as.character(vg) %in% as.character(val)) it works perfectly.   This shows that this is not a floating point problem. Using as.character is just a work-around.

Comment: You're entierly missing the point. Of **course** it works for character string comparisons.  When it comes to numbers, WYSINWYG.

Comment: And by the way,  there's a big difference between "expected answer"  and "correct answer."  Try not to confuse the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Andrie's comment, this ***is*** a floating point problem. To quote from the good book, [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

> Once we had crossed the Acheron, we arrived in the rst Circle, home of the
>   virtuous pagans. These are people who live in ignorance of the Floating Point
>   Gods. These pagans expect:

```
.1 == .3 / 3
[1] FALSE
```

> to be true.
>   The virtuous pagans will also expect:

```
seq(0, 1, by=.1) == .3
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

> to have exactly one value that is true.

In your example if we instead work with integers rather than floating point numbers it works:

```
vg   = rep(seq(90,110,1),90)
vals = seq(90,105,1)

for(val in vals){
  idx = c()
  idx = which((vg) %in% (val))
  cat(val,":",length(idx),"\t")
}

vg   = rep(seq(110,90,-1),90)
vals = seq(90,105,1)

for(val in vals){
  idx = c()
  idx = which((vg) %in% (val))
  cat(val,":",length(idx),"\t")
}
90 : 90         91 : 90         92 : 90         93 : 90         94 : 90         95 : 90         96 : 90
```

The R inferno is a really entertaining and informative reading. I highly recommend it.

You can also see that WYSINWYG by default by doing:

```
options(digits=22)
.3/3
[1] 0.09999999999999999167333
```

Comment: I understand the point.  But why does it show errors only for certain numbers and not for others? I don't get that part.

Comment: Because some of the fractional numbers are able to be represented exactly in floating point, whilst others are not. 0.1 is a good example of a number which is not able to be represented exactly in floating point, whilst 0.5 is. Try `library(gmp);as.bigq(0.1);as.bigq(0.5)` to see the fractional representations of these floating point numbers in memory.

Comment: I really appreciate the comments and feedback. I think I get the point.  Thank you Simon, Carl and Andrie.